# PyDrive Get the Backup List

Tags: google-drive-api, pydrive

I want to write a script that downloads backups from Google Drive. Then i will alter the backup and download it again.

I want to do it with PyDrive or directly Google Drive API but I couldn't find any documentation about "backups". I can search, modify, alter normal files and folders but not backups.

Is there any way of to download the backup files by API?